# How to detect the start of the history on an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe and button associated with this code:

```
$(".back").click(function() {
   window.history.back();
});
```

When I click on it, the history of the pages inside the iframe goes back. But how can I detect the starting page when the iframe was opened?

Comment: do you mean the starting page of the iframe or the starting page of the host page?

Comment: you can't use the set `src` value in the iframe?

Comment: @Mahan yes, I can set the src in the iframe, but how to know when should I set it?

Comment: Huh? Didn't you set it at the start?

Comment: If the iframe content is loaded using src, then the src value should be the first page, or not?

Comment: I don't understand, is this javascript inside the iframe or outside it in the page that contains the iFrame?

Comment: @Liam it is outside, in the page that contains the iframe

Comment: and you want to set the url inside the iframe or outside in the page itself?

Comment: @Liam outside in the page itself

Comment: Cool, so my answer (below) should work. Just needed to clarify.

Comment: @Liam I have a link that opens the iframe. I want to detect the click in "Go back" on the first page of the iframe, to show the page where the link is

Comment: Now I'm confused again?

Comment: @Liam sorry, I didn't explain welll at the beginning, take my last comment as good